# Callback Inside Callback

Tags: jquery, html, callback, fadein, jquery-callback

I'm trying to have a call back execute another when it finishes. But for some reason it's doing them all at once.

Here is the code:

```
$('video#videopromo').bind('ended',function()
{                  
    $("#hero").fadeIn("slow", function()
    {
        $(this).css("visibility", "visible");
        $("#videopromo").css({zIndex: -1});
        $(this).css("display", "block");

    });
});
```

I would like #hero to fade in as oppose to it displaying immediately would this be the best way?

Comment: Please provide HTML and/or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: your code works for me.

Comment: http://www.divisionforty.com/   If you click on watch video then skip to the end it just flips back doesn't fade

Comment: @cirrus is it fading at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put your code into jsFiddle and it works for me. Although I suspect you used `visibility:hidden` in your CSS whereas I've used `display:none`. I've commented out the css() code for (this) because I don't think you need it and I refactored it a little, but it works absolutely fine as it is;

```
#hero {    display:none; }
```

Here's some code that works (but your code works as is too with the above CSS);

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#videopromo").bind('click',function(e){  
        var videopromo = $(e.target);
        console.log(e.target);
        $("#hero").fadeIn("slow", function(){
              console.log("callback");
              //$(this).css({visibility:"visible",display:"block"});
              videopromo.css({zIndex: -1});
        });
    });
});
```

and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danieljsinclair/CqmSq/)

(click on 'video' to test)

Here's another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danieljsinclair/CqmSq/2/) that does the same using `visibility:hidden` as well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#videopromo").bind('click',function(e){  
        var videopromo = $(e.target);
        console.log(e.target);
      $("#hero").css({visibility:"visible"})
                .hide()
                .fadeIn( 500, function(){
                      console.log("fully faded in now");
                      videopromo.css({zIndex: -1});
                });
      });

});
```

Comment: problem i run into is because the video is positioned absolute the content that is below where it is goes behind the video/

Comment: Think i solved it:          $("#videopromo").css("position", "relative");

Comment: I've added another example that uses visibility for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into `.when` and `.done`.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/
http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

This will allow you to wait until something is finished before starting something else.

Comment: How would you implement that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by expanding on what @cirrus said Instead of hiding the element I've given the video a $("#videopromo").css("position", "relative"); on show so the content doesn't go in behind the video. Once its done it reverts!

Thanks

All for your help